# Network profiler on Android studio 3.0

Tags: android, android-studio, retrofit2, okhttp

I've been trying to use the new network profiler in AS 3.0.

My dependency stack:

```
retrofit 2.1.0
okhttp 3.3.1
```

The problem is when I enable advanced profiling it fails with following error:

> ```
> Caused by: java.net.ProtocolException: cannot write request body after response has been read
> at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:255)
> at com.android.tools.profiler.support.network.HttpURLConnection$.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnection$.java:282)
> at org.acra.util.HttpRequest.send(HttpRequest.java:147)
> at org.acra.sender.HttpSender.send(HttpSender.java:235)
> at org.acra.sender.ReportDistributor.sendCrashReport(ReportDistributor.java:102)
>
> at org.acra.sender.ReportDistributor.distribute(ReportDistributor.java:70)
>
> at org.acra.sender.SenderService.onHandleIntent(SenderService.java:69) 
> at android.app.IntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(IntentService.java:66)
>
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
> at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158) 
> at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
> ```

When I disable the advanced profiling, everything works correctly.

Comment: Probably your best solution is https://source.android.com/source/report-bugs

Answer (score 3):

I also experienced the same issue. I started getting error while my APP was in the background and processing incoming firebase notification (with data). The error was `"No implementation found for long com.android.tools.profiler.support.network.HttpTracker$Connection.nextId()`

(tried `Java_com_android_tools_profiler_support_network_HttpTracker_00024Connection_nextId`)

The error got resolved when I disabled "Advance Profiling Option" on Android studio **->** RUN **->** Edit Configuration **->** Profiling

Comment: Thanks. It woks for me ans saved lot of time.

Answer (score 1):

Go to Run -> Edit Configurations -> Profiling, and disable "Enable advanced profiling". This feature is not available with API <=19